# Pulling e-mail adress from website with VBA

Tags: vba, extract

I have a list of links an each link leads to homepage where one e-mail adress is listed. Is it possible with VBA to pull these e-mail into Excel somehow?

I would appreciate any help and advice.

Comment: "Is this possible?" Yes. This is not the answer you expected? Then please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question. We are not a code writing service. You have to post code for us to fix your problem.

Comment: This is answer I wanted. Before trying to do something I would like to know if it is actually possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an answer to my questions, unfortunately it is very specific due to my homepage being login protected so that you cannot try it out. I will post anyway and hope it can help somehow.

```
Sub emailextract()

    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    Dim ele As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim y As Integer


    For i = 1 To 150

    appIE.Visible = False
    #web-links are in Row A sheet "links"
    appIE.navigate Sheets("links").Range("A" & i)

    Do While appIE.Busy = True Or appIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


    y = i
    For Each ele In appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("dd")
        '
        Debug.Print ele.textContent

        Sheets("adressen").Range("A" & y).Value = ele.textContent
        y = y + 1


    Next

    Next i

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```